# Slick 3.1.1: Insert entity with its relations in a single transaction

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I have an entity Classified that has 2 relations: a Company and a Location. In order to persist the classified I need to know the ids of its relations which might require persisting an entity first (that is it might already exist in the database otherwise it should be inserted).

The ids are UUIDs assigned by the application (i.e. it's not autoincremented by the db) so the app assigns an id which will either end up being the entity id or be replaced by the actual id in the transaction if the entity already exists.

The code that does this is as follows:

```
def create(classified: Classified, company: Company, location: Location): Future[String] = {
val interaction = for {
  comp <- companies.filter(_.name === company.name).result.headOption flatMap {
    case None => companies returning companies.map(_.id) += company
    case Some(comp) => DBIO.successful(comp.id.get)
  }
  loc <- locations.filter(_.name === location.name).result.headOption flatMap {
    case None => locations returning locations.map(_.id) += location
    case Some(loc) => DBIO.successful(loc.id.get)
  }
  cl <- classifieds returning classifieds.map(_.id) += classified.copy(companyId = comp, locationId = loc)
} yield cl
db.run(interaction.transactionally)
```

}

The above works perfectly when ran against Postgres (which is the production database) but fails for H2 (which is the test and dev database) with the error: [SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT]

It looks like the H2 driver does not return ids unless they are of the autoincrement variety.

So, how can this transaction be written so that a) inserts happen in a single transaction b) with minimal db roundtrips and c) in a database neutral way ?

EDIT:

The above method is used from a controller like so:

```
classifiedDao.create(
      Classified(Some(UUID.randomUUID().toString), c.title, Jsoup.clean(c.body, Whitelist.basic()), c.refNo, "", ""),
      Company(Some(UUID.randomUUID().toString), c.companyName, c.companyEmail, None, None),
      Location(Some(UUID.randomUUID().toString), c.location, None)
    ).map(_ =>
      Redirect(routes.Classifieds.form()).flashing("success" -> "Classified submitted")
    )
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Do `company` and `location` already have an UUID assigned on insertion (line `case None => companies returning companies.map(_.id) += company`)?

Comment: Yes. The controller assigns ids to all three entities and then passes the objects to a DAO to be persisted, if the entity is already stored the id is discarded and the one retrieved from the db is used apart from the Classified is which is always used.

Comment: @Roman that comment was pure genius. In the None case I already know the id, all I need to do is sequence the result with the other DBActions and I am done. Thank you, that was brilliant. PS: I'm posting the answer below for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that retrieving the id from the db is the easy part since the code that does this already has the required type (DBIOAction), the hard part was getting the id after the insert but in that case I already knew the id because it's my code that set it. There's no need to use returning() and rely on the RDBMS.

Solution:

```
def create(classified: Classified, company: Company, location: Location): Future[String] = {
val interaction = for {
  comp <- companies.filter(_.name === company.name).result.headOption flatMap {
    case None => {
      companies += company
      DBIO.successful(company.id.get)
    }
    case Some(comp) => DBIO.successful(comp.id.get)
  }
  loc <- locations.filter(_.name === location.name).result.headOption flatMap {
    case None => {
      locations += location
      DBIO.successful(location.id.get)
    }
    case Some(loc) => DBIO.successful(loc.id.get)
  }
  cl <- {
    classifieds += classified.copy(companyId = comp, locationId = loc)
    DBIO.successful(classified.id.get)
  }
} yield cl
db.run(interaction.transactionally)
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You might consider using `DBIOAction.andThen` to ensure the insertion ran successfully: `(companies += company).andThen(DBIO.successful(company.id.get))`.

Answer (score 0):

*For Slick `returning` to work `Id` has to be `auto generated primary key`*

`Id` should not only be primary key but also auto increment id.

**Note**

*Many database systems only allow a single column to be returned which must be the table’s auto-incrementing primary key. If you ask for other columns a SlickException is thrown at runtime (unless the database actually supports it).*

So write a function which returns `Id` after inserting in the database like this.

```
def getIdAfterInsert(entity: Entity): DBIO[EntityId] = {
  (entities += entity).flatMap { _ =>
    entities.filter(_.name === entity.name).result.flatMap {
      case Some(entity) => DBIO.successful(entity.id)
      case None => DBIO.fail(new Exception("something terrible happened"))
    }
  }.transactionally
}
```